# How to change .click(), fadein, and fadeout from jQuery to pure JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this project which requires me to use table and forbids me to use any `<div>` tags and jQuery.

I want to make a slider in one row of my table. I want the image to change with a click on other image in the second row. I've managed to do that using this code:

```
function changeImage(a) {
    document.getElementById("imgblockjs").src=a;
}
```

And the html:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<TITLE>
    Home -- RTR
</TITLE>    

<LINK REL="ICON" TYPE="IMAGE/PNG" HREF="../img/logo.png" /> 
<SCRIPT src="../script.js"></SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <table border="0" width="100%" height="10px" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" >

            <img id="imgblockjs" src="../img/singa.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" />

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" id="imgchanger">

    <a href="#"><img src="../img/singa.jpg" id="imgthumb1" onclick="changeImage('../img/lion.jpg');"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/gajah.jpg" id="imgthumb2" onclick="changeImage('../img/elephant.jpg');"></a>

    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But that code doesn't have any transition.

After hours research on the internet, I found a jQuery code which works nicely:

```
$("#imgthumb1").click(function() {
    $("#imgblockjs").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $("#imgblockjs").attr("src",$("#imgthumb1").attr("href"));
    }).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});

$("#imgthumb2").click(function() {
    $("#imgblockjs").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $("#imgblockjs").attr("src",$("#imgthumb2").attr("href"));
    }).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});

$("#imgthumb3").click(function() {
    $("#imgblockjs").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $("#imgblockjs").attr("src",$("#imgthumb3").attr("src"));
    }).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});

$("#imgthumb4").click(function() {
    $("#imgblockjs").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $("#imgblockjs").attr("src",$("#imgthumb4").attr("src"));
    }).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});
```

with the html:

```
<tr><td colspan="4">
<img id="imgblockjs" src="../img/singa.jpg" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="4">

<a id="imgthumb1" href="../img/singa.jpg"><img src="../img/singa.jpg" /></a>
<a id="imgthumb2" href="../img/gajah.jpg"><img src="../img/gajah.jpg" /></a>

</td></tr>
```

But as I said before, I mustn't use jQuery. How can I convert the jQuery code to pure JavaScript code? Or I would be happy if there's any other suggestions.

Note, I simplified my html on purpose. Also, if possible I don't want any CSS because it may mess with original CSS file, but simple and short CSS is acceptable.

Comment: Note that "please convert this code for me" requests are discouraged here, since they are too broad, and if we allowed them volunteers would be inundated with free work. Please always be willing to make the bulk of the effort yourself, and show what you have tried before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Below is vanilla JavaScript for changing the image from the thumbnails.

```
var changeImage = document.getElementById("imgblockjs");

document.getElementById("imgthumb1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    changeImage.setAttribute("src", this.getAttribute("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

However with this code you will not have the animation attached.
If you would like vanilla JavaScript animation there is **very little support for that across browsers.** You can check out more about that here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

```
 document.getElementById("imgthumb2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var self = this;
      var animStart = changeImage.animate([{
          opacity: 1
      }, {
          opacity: 0
      }], {
         duration: 1000
      })

animStart.onfinish  = function() {
    changeImage.setAttribute("src", self.getAttribute("href"));
    changeImage.animate([{
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        opacity: 1
    }], {
        duration: 1000
    });

}

e.preventDefault();
})
```

If you like animations but would like to avoid jQuery you can use GSAP JavaScript animation library from here https://greensock.com/. Or you can always use a CSS animation option.

I hope this helps a little.